# Measurable Functions over finite or countables sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a countable or finite set and $u$ a measure over $(X,\Sigma)$. Let $A=${$A_1,A_2,...$} be the set of atoms of $(X,\Sigma)$. Prove that if $f: X\to \mathbb R $ is a measurable function, then $f$ is constant over each atom $A_i$, meaning: If $x$,$y$ $\in$ $A_i$ then is true that $f(x)=f(y)$.

I have really no clue about how to prove this.

Comment: Show why a function that is not constant over an atom isn't measurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Assume $f(x) \neq f(y)$.

Can you think about a measurable set, containing $f(x)$ but not containing $f(y)$ ?

What can we do with such set, knowing that $f$ is measurable?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is what i managed to write:
Since $f$ is measurable, ${f^{-1}}(-\infty,a]$ $\in$ $\Sigma$ $\forall a\in \mathbb R$. 
Supouse that $f(x) \neq f(y)$. Then, exists a $c$ such that $f(x) < c < f(y)$. So, if we consider the set {$f$ $\leq$ $c$}, $x$ $\in$ {$f$ $\leq$ $c$} but $y$ $\notin$ {$f$ $\leq$ $c$}.
But i'm stuck here. I don't know what the next step would be, can i say something about the Atoms? Since $x,y$ $\in$ $A_i$, where $A_i$ is an atom?

Comment: So what can you say about the sets $A_i \cap \{f \leq c\}$ and $A_i \cap \{f > c\}$?

Comment: The first set containts $x$ and the second $y$ ?

Comment: Yes, so the sets are both nonempty. What are their union and intersection?

Comment: Their intersection is $\emptyset$ and their union is $A_i$. Does that means that both $x$ and $y$ are atoms and we have a contradiction?

Comment: Well, it means that $A_i \cap \{f \leq c\}$ and $A_i \cap \{f > c\}$ are both nonempty proper subsets of $A_i$, so they are not measurable. What does that imply about $\{f \leq c\}$ and $\{f > c\}$? Can they be measurable?

Comment: I think i'm not seeing something. Why does that implies that they are not measurable? I'm thinking that latter i could say that {$f$ $\leq$ $c$} and {$f$ > $c$} not belong to $\Sigma$.

Comment: $A_i$ is an atom, so it has positive measure, but any proper measurable subset has measure zero Therefore if $A_i \cap \{f \leq c\}$ and $A_i \cap \{f > c\}$ are measurable, they both have measure zero, and therefore so does their union $A_i$. This is a contradiction, so one of $A_i \cap \{f \leq c\}$ and $A_i \cap \{f > c\}$ must not be measurable, and therefore neither is measurable.

Comment: Meaning that {$f$ $\leq$ $c$} $\notin$ $\Sigma$ and {$f$ > $c$} $\notin$ $\Sigma$. So $f$ is not measurable and that is a contradiction to our hypothesis!! Thank you very much, you're very patient!

Comment: Yes, that concludes the proof!